# c# WIA dialog showing paper sizes dropdown

Tags: c#, size, scanning, wia

Using C# to acquire image from a Canon scanner. Using the following code and it works fine,

```
 public ImageFile Scan()
 {
        ImageFile image;

        try
        {
            CommonDialog dialog = new CommonDialog();

            image = dialog.ShowAcquireImage(
                    WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType,
                    WiaImageIntent.ColorIntent,
                    WiaImageBias.MinimizeSize,
                    WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG, 
                    true, 
                    true, 
                    false);

            return image;
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == -2145320939)
            {
                throw new ScannerNotFoundException();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ScannerException("COM Exception", ex);
            }
        }
  }
```

This launches a window like below,

[image]

The scan works fine. No issues. But i want to add a "predefined" rectangle sizes(paper sizes like A3, A4, A5 etc) dropdown to this dialog for the user to select an appropriate size for scan.

How can i add controls to this dialog through c# WIA?

Answer (score 0):

**By setting all the bool properties false.**

```
public ImageFile Scan()
 {
        ImageFile image;

        try
        {
            CommonDialog dialog = new CommonDialog();

            image = dialog.ShowAcquireImage(
                    WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType,
                    WiaImageIntent.ColorIntent,
                    WiaImageBias.MinimizeSize,
                    WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG, 
                    false, 
                    false, 
                    false);

            return image;
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == -2145320939)
            {
                throw new ScannerNotFoundException();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ScannerException("COM Exception", ex);
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks